# HTML new line makes white space

Tags: php, html

I have problem with my HTML code inside the echo. This is my code:

```
echo "<tr><td class=\"desc\">
                            <div class=\"tit\">
                                <img class=\"unit u".$i."\" src=\"img/x.gif\" alt=\"".$unit_name."\" title=\"".$unit_name."\" />
                                <a href=\"#\" onClick=\"return Popup(".$i.",1);\">".$unit_name."</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class=\"details\">
                                <img class=\"r1\" src=\"img/x.gif\" alt=\"".$lang['resources']['Lumber']."\" title=\"".$lang['resources']['Lumber']."\" />".${'bs'.$i}['wood']."|
                                <img class=\"r2\" src=\"img/x.gif\" alt=\"".$lang['resources']['Clay']."\" title=\"".$lang['resources']['Clay']."\" />".${'bs'.$i}['clay']."|
                                <img class=\"r3\" src=\"img/x.gif\" alt=\"".$lang['resources']['Iron']."\" title=\"".$lang['resources']['Iron']."\" />".${'bs'.$i}['iron']."|
                                <img class=\"r4\" src=\"img/x.gif\" alt=\"".$lang['resources']['Crop']."\" title=\"".$lang['resources']['Crop']."\" />".${'bs'.$i}['crop']."|
                                <img class=\"clock\" src=\"img/x.gif\" alt=\"".$lang['gameplay']['duration']."\" title=\"".$lang['gameplay']['duration']."\" />";
```

Now i have a problem that if I put those `<img class` things in each line, get space after `|` but if I put them in same line like `<img class>|<img class>` than no white space between them.

So actually my result looks like this:

```
Lumber21312| Clay21312| Iron2312| Crop2132|
```

I want it look like this:

```
Lumber21312|Clay21312|Iron2312|Crop2132|
```

Sorry if I wasn't so clear :$

Comment: So you've determined that adding a whitespace character to the source will cause the browser to render a space, and you don't want the browser to render a space … so don't put a whitespace character in the document.

Comment: I don't white space there, I just want to have them in each line because its better for my eye than having a line long 300 characters

Comment: In HTML, spaces are collapsed but not ignored.

Comment: so is there way to remove it?

Comment: Dzoki, that was no stupid comment.

Comment: solution is not `dont write it (space)` solution is to echo it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echo it out like

```
"<img />".
"|".
"<img />".
```

etc. Then you can put as much whitespace in there as you want, and it won't render.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the indentation space, it's causing the whitespace.

```
<img />|<img />|<img />|...
```

Comment: I don't want to have it in same line, because lines are long and I want to have it in each line